# Why do we divide to remove elements considered equivalent?

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose we have a set of $N$ elements, each of which is considered distintic from all others. If we ask ourselves the number of ways to order those $N$ elements the reasoning is based on this: for the first element we have $N$ choices, since they are all equivalent after removing the first, there are $N-1$ choices for the second and so on. In the end there are $N!$ ways to order the elements.

A concrete problem of that kind is basically to count the number of ways to order $N$ balls which are considered different one from the other.

Another problem is if we have the set of $N$ elements and we divide it into two disjoint sets $A$ and $B$, the first with $n_1$ elements and the second with $n_2$ elements. If we consider the elements of the set $A$ equivalent and the elements from the set $B$ equivalent, then the situation changes.

In fact, for a concrete example, if we consider $N$ balls, with $n_1$ red and $n_2$ blue the set of balls is divided into disjoint sets. Now, in that case the reasoning I presented fails, because there are equivalent sequences and I know that intuitively.

Now people usually say "the number of ways to order the elements in that situation is $N!/n_1!n_2!$ where we divide $n_1!$ and $n_2!$ because the red balls are equal and the blue balls are equal.

Now, why division solves this problem? The principle of counting states that if there are $n_1$ ways of doing $A$ and $n_2$ ways of doing $B$ there are $n_1n_2$ ways of doing $A$ and $B$. This other argument seems like saying that we can use division to remove things we count that we don't want to count.

This argument of dividing by the number of ways to do something because we need to exclude something from the counting is quite commom but I don't understand it. So my question is: why do we divide by the number of ways to order the red balls in order to remove the sequences we counted as different that in truth are equivalent? What this argument of dividing is all about?

Comment: The way I like to understand it is this: Imagine for a moment that we have labelled all of the balls so that we can distinguish them all. Then we can certainly arrange them in N! different ways. Now, think about one particular way in which they can be arranged in the original sense (labels removed). How many times did that occur in our N! arrangements? The balls from set A could have been rearranged at will, and independent of that so could the balls from set B. So for each distinguishable arrangement, there are $n_1 ! \cdot n_2 !$ arrangements of specific balls that produce it.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a concrete example.  Let there be five balls, numbered from $1$ to $5$.  As you say, there are $5!=120$ ways to put them in order. Now paint balls $1$ and $2$ red.  We can match each of the $120$ orders with another one that has $1$ and $2$ swapped, leaving us with $60=120/2!$ pairs.  We can't tell the two orders in a pair apart any more because we don't know which ball is which, so there are $60$ orders with two red balls and three numbered balls.  We can again group these into $10$ groups of $6$ where each group has the two red balls in the same location and only differs in the order of $3,4,5$.  Note that $10={5\choose 2}$ is the number of ways to choose the locations of the two red balls.  Now paint balls $3,4,5$ blue.  We can't distinguish any of the six orders in a group for the same reason.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider those arguments as shorthand for arguments that involve only what you've called the principle of counting. This is much like $a/b=q$ can be thought as just saying $a=bq$. For example your problem about red and blue balls could go like this:

**Q**: How many "interleavings" of $n_1$ red balls and $n_2$ blue balls are there, that is, how many ways are there to order the balls if we don't care about the relative order of balls of the same color?

**A**: Let's count the total number of orderings of the balls, where the order of balls of the same color *does* matter, in two different ways:

1. Since there are $n_1 + n_2$ balls, there are $(n_1+n_2)!$ orderings of them.
2. Call the answer of the question we're trying to solve $K$. To pick an ordering of all balls you can pick:

   - any of the $K$ ways to interleave the red and blue balls,
   - any of the $n_1!$ ways to order the red balls, and
   - any of the $n_2!$ ways to order the blue balls.

Comparing we get that $(n_1+n_2)! = K n_1! n_2!$.